# Which planets of our solar system could be discovered from another solar system with present technology?

Tags: astronomy, exoplanets

Recently many exoplanets have been found orbiting nearby stars. Assume there is a civilization with identical technology residing in a nearby (< 100 light years) solar system. Could they discover Earth or other planets orbiting the Sun?

Comment: Probably more suitable for [astronomy.se].

Answer (score 0):

They probably could, but if they were identical, as they would have the understanding of gravity, doppler effect, spectrography, and it's applications to chemical analysis to spot us.